# express formidable methods where are they?

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

i have an importante question with this code

```
form
    .on('error', function(err) {
        throw err;
    })

    .on('field', function(field, value) {
        //receive form fields here
    })

    /* this is where the renaming happens */
    .on ('fileBegin', function(name, file){
            //rename the incoming file to the file's name
            file.path = form.uploadDir + "/" + file.name;
    })

    .on('file', function(field, file) {
        //On file received
    })

    .on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        //self.emit('progess', bytesReceived, bytesExpected)

        var percent = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected * 100) | 0;
        process.stdout.write('Uploading: %' + percent + '\r');
    })
```

these are methods of the formidable module... i discover that the express.bodyParser use formidable module... but i wanna call method on.('fileBegin'... with express and i cant

where is the method... where is the object form

as you see the object form has the fields and files

in express.bodyParser the files are in req.files and the fields are in req.body
but when i try to call req.on('fileBegin'... gives me an error

anybody try this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `formidable` object is simply a local variable within `connect.multipart` and never gets attached to `req`. Looks you'll have to roll your own middleware, using `connect.multipart` as a guide (it's actually pretty short and simple).

Comment: You have the source code to `connect.multipart` since connect comes with express. As I said, it's quite short and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

The `defer` option has been added to `multipart`:

```
app.use(connect.multipart({ defer: true }));
```

Later…

```
app.post('/foo', function (request, response, next) {
  // setting defer exposes multipart's internal IncomingForm object
  var form = request.form; 
});
```